# Wordpress "The Events Calendar" editing the month view

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am working to edit the month view of "The Events Calendar" in Wordpress.  I cannot seem to figure out which files contain the relevant markup. The file structure seems to make sense, however, when I edit anything with /month no changes reflect.

**The File Structure**

[image: FILE STRUCTURE]

**Core Plugin Files**
  .../plugins/the-events-calendar/src/views/

Here we have several folders with the different views. One of which is "month" and, according to the documentation, contains the files I wish to edit.

**Theme Files**
  .../mytheme/tribe-events/

This is the folder the documentation told me to create to place edited templates in.

**The Fubar** 
When i follow the documentation for editing a single event located in /list everything works as expected.  All I need to do is create a subfolder in mytheme/tribe-events/list and put a new file within to override the original.

When I repeat these same steps in order to edit a file within /month view things are different. For some reason none of my changes work. Outside of the /month folder in /views there is a month.php file which contains the following...

```
do_action( 'tribe_events_before_template' );

// Title Bar
tribe_get_template_part( 'month/title-bar' );

// Tribe Bar
tribe_get_template_part( 'modules/bar' );

//  - My Custom Code - 
write_log('This Log Works');
// Main Events Content
tribe_get_template_part( 'month/content' );

do_action( 'tribe_events_after_template' );
```

> > Note: write_log() is a function I use in php for debugging. It's essentially a console.log but appends the data to the end of the error.log file which i have being read by a terminal.  I do not believe the issue is with this function as I have tested other methods.

The "month" file echoes my log just fine. However, when I add the same log into any of the files it is pulling from the 'month/' directory I get nothing.  I went through every file in the subdirectories and added a log and realized that they all work except any file within /month

I thought maybe the issue was with the plugins' "tribe_get_template_part()" function pointing to the wrong place so I decided to eliminate the "am i making this child plugin right" variables and just start editing the plugin files directly.  But I get the exact same behavior. I got so desperate that I deleted the entire /months folder from the plugin and the calendar still worked!

So obviously I am really missing something but currently I am at a loss.

This documentation is what I've been following to figure this out.
https://support.theeventscalendar.com/153124-Themers-Guide

The only thing I can think of at this point is that the javascript templating system built into the plugin is working some hidden magic but the fact that I can delete the entire months folder leaves me at a loss.

Comment: Do you have some sort of caching in place?

Comment: I do not think this is a caching problem but I could be wrong. I am working on a custom theme in a wordpress installation so I am aware of no caching aside from normal browser caching.  I was mashing hard refresh on my browser in pure desperation because it was the only thing that I could think of.

Comment: Here is the correct path.
plugins/the-events-calendar/src/views/v2/month

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this still, I also had the same issue and solved it by disabling the Month View Cache under Event Settings > Display. Screenshot:

[image: Disabling Month View Caching]